# Suddenly, VS Code has stopped identifying the variables

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Suddenly, VS Code has stopped identifying the variables. They used to be highlighted in light blue but now, they are just plain white. Any error in syntax is also not detected. The autocomplete is also not working. Only flutter is showing this problem. My VS Code is working file with java.

PS: Already tried restarting, deleting and installing dart and flutter extensions, already tried flutter clean, upgrade pub get, and flutter doctor is showing everything file.

Here is the screenshot of variables not being identified:
[image: Here is the screenshot of variables not being identified.]

Auto complete is not working as well:
[image: Auto complete is not working as well]

All what I have tried did not fix the problem. A day before, everything was working fine but now, this occurred.

Comment: Are there any errors listed if you click "Help" -> "Toggle Developer Tools" and then click on the Console tab? If you want to try re-installing the extension, you might need to uninstall it and then delete the Dart-Code folders from ~/.extensions because otherwise they're not really re-installed, the old copy is reused.